# On click show span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide span under another span and when someone click on the upper most span it should disappear and show the contents beneath it.

MY HTML:

```
<span id="couponCode" style="display:inline-block;border:2px dashed;padding:5px;margin:5px;background:#EE4000;color:white;height:20px;text-align:center;">{{ i.couponCode }}</span><span class="cTs">Click to see code</span>
```

My CSS:

```
.cTs
{
    left :0px;
    padding:10px;
    height:50px;
    color:white;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: black;  
}
```

but i am unable to position the  over the first span...instead it appear on the right of the first span....can someone please help me...

Comment: You probably need to position the `Click to see code` using absolute positioning. Check out the result of [absolute positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/hJ983/). Tweak it as you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the elements inside a `position: relative;` container, and than use `position: absolute;` with `top` and `left` values for inner elements

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

div span:nth-of-type(1) {
    z-index: 1;    
}

div span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5rxa/)

Using an [`onclick`](http://jsfiddle.net/n5rxa/1/) event